# Olingo: Exposing generic classes strategy

Tags: java, odata, olingo

Guess this Storage class:

```
class Storage {
    List<Entity> entities;
}

class Entity {
  String id;
  List<Property> properties;
}

class abstract Property<T> {
    String key;
    List<T> values;
}

class StringProperty extends Property<String> {}
class NumberProperty extends Property<BigDecimal> {}
class DateProperty extends Property<Date> {}
```

So, I've a list of entities which has some properties:

I want to expose this schema using olingo. So my provider:

```
public class EntitiesEdmProvider extends CsdlAbstractEdmProvider {

    // Service Namespace
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "swiller.odata.sample";

    // EDM Container
    public static final String CONTAINER_NAME = "Container";
    public static final FullQualifiedName CONTAINER_FQN = new FullQualifiedName(NAMESPACE, CONTAINER_NAME);

    // Entity Types Names
    public static final FullQualifiedName ET_ENTITY = new FullQualifiedName(NAMESPACE, "Entity");

    // Complex Types Names
   public static final FullQualifiedName CT_PROPERTY = new FullQualifiedName(NAMESPACE, "Property");

    @Override
    public CsdlEntityType getEntityType(final FullQualifiedName entityTypeName) throws ODataException {
        if (ET_ENTITY.equals(entityTypeName)) {
          return new CsdlEntityType()
            .setName(ET_RESOURCE.getName())
            .setKey(Arrays.asList(new CsdlPropertyRef().setName("Id")))
            .setProperties(
              Arrays.asList(
                  new CsdlProperty().setName("Id").setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int16.getFullQualifiedName()
              )
            ).setNavigationProperties(
              Arrays.asList(
                new CsdlNavigationProperty().setName("Properties").setType(CT_PROPERTY).setCollection(true)
              )
          );
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CsdlComplexType getComplexType(final FullQualifiedName complexTypeName) throws ODataException {
      if (CT_PROPERTY.equals(complexTypeName)) {
          return new CsdlComplexType().setName(CT_PROPERTY.getName()).setProperties(
            Arrays.asList(
              new CsdlProperty().setName("Key").setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String.getFullQualifiedName()),
              new CsdlProperty().setName("Value").setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.<<<<<<????>>>>>>.getFullQualifiedName()),
            )
          );
        }
}
```

The main problem appears when I'm using this approach is that I don't know what to write on `<<<<<<????>>>>>>`. Any ideas?

I've also thought about exposing three list of properties:

```
.setNavigationProperties(
    Arrays.asList(
        new CsdlNavigationProperty().setName("StringProperties").setType(CT_STRING_PROPERTY).setCollection(true),
    new CsdlNavigationProperty().setName("NumberProperties").setType(CT_NUMBER_PROPERTY).setCollection(true),
    new CsdlNavigationProperty().setName("DateProperties").setType(CT_DATE_PROPERTY).setCollection(true)
    )
)
```

And

```
public CsdlComplexType getComplexType(final FullQualifiedName complexTypeName) throws ODataException {
  if (CT_STRING_PROPERTY.equals(complexTypeName)) {
    return new CsdlComplexType().setName(CT_PROPERTY.getName()).setProperties(
      Arrays.asList(
        new CsdlProperty().setName("Key").setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String.getFullQualifiedName()),
        new CsdlProperty().setName("Value").setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String.getFullQualifiedName())
      )
    );
  else if (CT_NUMBER_PROPERTY.equals(complexTypeName)) {...}
  else if (CT_DATE_PROPERTY.equals(complexTypeName)) {...}
  return null;
}
```

So, which are the cons of exposing three collections binded to its types? Is there any best-way to get it?

I don't know if I've explained so well.